# HQL Left Outer Join for null column in one-to-one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, left-join

Left outer join is supposed to get all data from left table no matter if there is matching record from B table, however if left tables right_id column is null, records cant be got.

I am explaining more

In Data model: Order.java, it is my LEFT table, there is a one to one relation

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = OrderShippingDetail.class, optional=true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "SHIPPING_DETAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private OrderShippingDetail shippingDetail;
```

and HQL is:

```
    hql = "SELECT " +
            "o.id as id, " +
            "o.createTime as createTime, " +
            "o.customerEmailAddress as customerEmailAddress, " +
            "o.customerPhoneNumber as customerPhoneNumber, " +
            "o.customerNote as customerNote, " +
            "o.invoicePrintedFlag as invoicePrintedFlag, " +
            "shippingAddress.address.personName as shippingPersonName, " +
            "shippingDetail.shippingCompany.id as shippingCompanyId, "+
            "shippingDetail.shippingCompany.name as shippingCompanyName, "+
            "shippingDetail.receiptNumber as shippingReceiptNumber, "+
            "shippingDetail.trackingNumber as shippingTrackingNumber, "+
            "shippingDetail.price as shippingPrice, "+
            "o.invoiceNumber as invoiceNumber " + 
        "FROM Order AS o " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingAddress AS shippingAddress " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingDetail AS shippingDetail ";
```

But there comes just records which "SHIPPING_DETAIL_ID" is NOT null. Is there an error with HQL? It is created by modelling SQL command which is automatically created when hibernate runs.

I found this,

> HQL supports two forms of association joining: implicit and explicit.
>
> The queries shown in the previous section all use the explicit form,
>   that is, where the join keyword is explicitly used in the from clause.
>   This is the recommended form.
>
> The implicit form does not use the join keyword. Instead, the
>   associations are "dereferenced" using dot-notation. implicit joins can
>   appear in any of the HQL clauses. implicit join result in inner joins
>   in the resulting SQL statement.

And I remove my dot notation in the SELECT part, so my new HQL:

```
hql = "SELECT " +
                "o.id as id, " +
                "o.createTime as createTime, " +
                "o.customerEmailAddress as customerEmailAddress, " +
                "o.customerPhoneNumber as customerPhoneNumber, " +
                "o.customerNote as customerNote, " +
                "o.invoicePrintedFlag as invoicePrintedFlag, " +
                "shippingDetail, " +
                "o.invoiceNumber as invoiceNumber " + 
            "FROM Order AS o " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingAddress AS shippingAddress " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingDetail AS shippingDetail ";
```

So, it works, it returns all records in Order table, however, I dont want to select all columns and relations in the ShippingDetail object. What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add another explicit left join to the query:

```
SELECT o.id as id, 
...,
shippingCompany.id as shippingCompanyId, 
shippingCompany.name as shippingCompanyName, 
...
FROM Order AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingAddress AS shippingAddress 
LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingDetail AS shippingDetail
LEFT OUTER JOIN shippingDetail.shippingCompany AS shippingCompany
```

Comment: I should have got it!  `shippingDetail.shippingCompany.id as shippingCompanyId` First dot is for `LEFT OUTER JOIN o.shippingDetail AS shippingDetail` and second one cause an INNER JOIN according to Hibernate documentation. thanks...